# Array & slideshow

Tags: slideshow

I'm using the below code in order to display a photo in slide show, i need to display: name,job and quote for each person, but actually only photos change on time interval specified ...can anyone help?

```
 var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
 var testname = document.getElementById("testname");
 var testjob = document.getElementById("testjob");
 var testpa = document.getElementById("testpa");

            var currentPos = 0;
            var images = ["ch1.jpg", "ch2.jpg", "ch3.jpg"]
            var testname = [“John Smith” ,”Jan Rosso”,”Raphael Matthew”]
            var testjob = [“Manager” ,”Director”,”Supervisor”]
            var testpa = [“I like this company”,”It’s amazing”,”Wondeful atmospher”]
            
            function volgendefoto() {
                if (++currentPos >= images.length)
                    currentPos = 0;

                img1.src = images[currentPos];
                 testname.value = testname[currentPos];
                  testjob.value = testjob[currentPos];
                   testpa.value = testpa[currentPos];
            }

            setInterval(volgendefoto, 3000);
    function test(){
    document.getElementById('text').value=document.getElementById('testname').value
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

testName and the others may need to be updated via innerHTML

```
 function volgendefoto() {
            if (++currentPos >= images.length)
                currentPos = 0;

            img1.src = images[currentPos];
            testname.innerHtml = testname[currentPos];
            testjob.innerHtml = testjob[currentPos];
            testpa.innerHtml = testpa[currentPos];
        }
```

Comment: Thanx Slipoch, but it still doesn't work ...do u have any other solution?